# Define Date format, regex match, and check validity - Peer Review

Tags: php, regex, performance, date

I'm writing a input validation method for codeigniter to check date format.  I'm actually just doing it in a test script to get the functionality nailed down.  I've got something that works but I'd just like see if I'm approaching this the best (or worst) way.

Really specifically I'm looking at the second half, I've commented to point out what I mean.

```
<?

$input = $_POST['input'];   //text input of intended format
$date  = $_POST['date'];    //text input of date in matching format
                            //examples: y-m-d, Y.M.D, m/D/Y  (Case has no affect)

//I'm setting up a regex string based on given format
$pattern = preg_replace('/[yY]/','([0-9]{4})',$input);
$pattern = preg_replace('/[mM]/','([0-9]{1,2})',$pattern);
$pattern = preg_replace('/[dD]/','([0-9]{1,2})',$pattern);

//escaping slashes (if used as date delimiter)
$pattern = str_replace('/','\/',$pattern);


echo "Format  : " . $input . "<br />";
echo "Date    : " . $date . "<br/>";
echo "============" . "<br />";
echo "<br/>";

//if given date matches given format
if(preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'$/',$date,$matches)) {
    echo 'YAY A MATCH! <br/>';

    //From here down seems like it could be improved, seems a bit brute force
    //All of this below, is trying to get the order of the format so I can feed the proper values
    //to the checkdate() function to check date validity.

    preg_match('/[yY]/', $input, $match_year,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    preg_match('/[mM]/', $input, $match_month,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    preg_match('/[dD]/', $input, $match_day,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if ($match_year[0][1] < $match_month[0][1] && $match_year[0][1] < $match_day[0][1]) {
        $year = $matches[1];
        array_splice($matches,1,1);
    }
    else if ($match_year[0][1] > $match_month[0][1] && $match_year[0][1] > $match_day[0][1]) {
        $year = $matches[3];
        array_splice($matches,3,1);
    }
    else {
        $year = $matches[2];
        array_splice($matches,2,1);
    }

    if ($match_month[0][1] < $match_day[0][1]) {
        $month = $matches[1];
        $day   = $matches[2];
    }
    else {
        $month = $matches[2];
        $day   = $matches[1];
    }

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $month . ' / ' . $day . ' / ' . $year . "<br/>";

    if (checkdate($month,$day,$year)) { 
        echo "This is a valid date."; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo "This is not a valid date"; 
    } 
} 
else {
    echo "Given date does not match given format"; 
}
```

Comment: which part? no I just thought it was the best option, as I want to accept both lowercase and upppercase letters for the format, and validate the inputs as numbers with the correct amount of digits.

Comment: What sort of letters do you mean?  On first glance, it looks like it's only matching on numbers, which makes sense for a date.

Comment: If you look at all your use cases are you possibly only really going to be handling US (mm-dd--yy) UK (dd-mm-yy) or SQL (yyyy-mm-dd) type dates? If so just input a constant ie $input = "US", all you want to do is explode() on the possible delineators (. / - [space]) and in the "year" expand 12 to 2012 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do it all in one regex using [named subpatterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)?

```
$search = array(
    '/[yY]/',
    '/[mM]/',
    '/[dD]/',
);
$replace = array(
    '(?P<year>[0-9]{4})',
    '(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})',
    '(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})',
);
$pattern = preg_replace($search, $replace, $input);
```

Then, just run it against the input:

```
if (preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $date, $match)) {
    $year = $match['year'];
    $month = $match['month'];
    $day = $match['day'];
} else {
    echo "Date not in proper format";
}
```

But in general depending on your needs I'd just use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [`date_parse_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)...

Comment: awesome, just cut about 25-30 lines of code, thanks, I really like the array method of using preg_replace and using the named subpatterns seems extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? PHP has several ways to determine whether or not something is a valid date, and those are done, stable, and faster to use.

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

$dates = array(
    '18-01-2011 16:22',
    '2011-01-18 16:22',
    '11-01-18 16:22'
);

foreach( $dates as $date ) {
    echo strftime( '%Y-%m-%d', strtotime( $date ) ) . "\n";
}
```

These dates are all successfully parsed, and the result is 2011-01-18 for each of those. If we're talking about the formatting itself, you might wish to consider the following:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

$dates = array(
    '18-01-2011 16:22',
    '2011-01-18 16:22',
    '11-01-18 16:22'
);

$formats = array(
    'Y-m-d',
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'd-m-y',
    'd/m/Y'
);

foreach( $dates as $date ) {
    if( strtotime( $date ) ) { // validate date.
        $datetime = new DateTime( $date );
        foreach( $formats as $format ) {
            echo $datetime->format( $format ) . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think writing a function for dates should be necessary for PHP these days, we have all the tools in the language? Here's some documentation:

- [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)
- [DateTime object](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: +1 for "PHP has several ways". `date_parse_from_format()` fits perfectly. PHP 5.3.0 though.

Comment: My requirement is 5.1.x per Codeigniter 2.0 (reactor), and no, I don't see your point, my specific use case needs to accept a formatting value, a date, make sure the date matches the formatting value, and that it is a valid date.  Your answer boils down to "PHP has plenty of date functions, use em."  Which isn't really all that helpful at this point.  Feel free to update your answer specifically geared towards my actual needs.